# How to render a confusion matrix visualization in a Kubeflow pipeline component step?

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

Here is what I am trying from one of the official tutorials

```
import kfp
import kfp.dsl as dsl
from kfp.components import create_component_from_func    

@create_component_from_func
def confusion_visualization(matrix_uri: str = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubeflow/pipelines/master/samples/core/visualization/confusion_matrix.csv') -> NamedTuple('VisualizationOutput', [('mlpipeline_ui_metadata', 'UI_metadata')]):
    """Provide confusion matrix csv file to visualize as metrics."""
    import json

    metadata = {
        'outputs' : [{
          'type': 'confusion_matrix',
          'format': 'csv',
          'schema': [
            {'name': 'target', 'type': 'CATEGORY'},
            {'name': 'predicted', 'type': 'CATEGORY'},
            {'name': 'count', 'type': 'NUMBER'},
          ],
          'source': matrix_uri,
          'labels': ['rose', 'lily', 'iris'],
        }]
    }
    
    print('Printing the metadata')
    print(metadata)

    from collections import namedtuple
    visualization_output = namedtuple('VisualizationOutput', [
        'mlpipeline_ui_metadata'])
    print()
    return visualization_output(json.dumps(metadata))

@dsl.pipeline(
    name='confusion-matrix-pipeline',
    description='A sample pipeline to generate Confusion Matrix for UI visualization.'
)
def confusion_matrix_pipeline():
    confusion_visualization_task = confusion_visualization('results.json')
    
    
client = kfp.Client()
client.create_run_from_pipeline_func(
    confusion_matrix_pipeline,
    arguments={}
)
```

I am not able to see a visualization in neither of the Run output or Visualizations tab. It says there are no visualizations in this step. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think an issue with your code is that you don't provide the output as a file (try using an `OutputPath`).

From [Kubeflow docs](https://v1-5-branch.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/sdk/output-viewer/#v1-sdk-writing-out-metadata-for-the-output-viewers):

> The component must also export a file output artifact with an artifact
> name of mlpipeline-ui-metadata, or else the Kubeflow Pipelines UI will
> not render the visualization.

> ...
> If the component writes such a file to its container filesystem, the
> Kubeflow Pipelines system extracts the file, and the Kubeflow
> Pipelines UI uses the file to generate the specified viewer(s). The
> metadata specifies where to load the artifact data from. The Kubeflow
> Pipelines UI loads the data into memory and renders it.

The [Kubeflow docs](https://v1-5-branch.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/sdk/output-viewer/#confusion-matrix-1) also provide an example, which is working for me:

```
def confusion_matrix_viz(mlpipeline_ui_metadata_path: kfp.components.OutputPath()):
  import json
    
  metadata = {
    'outputs' : [{
      'type': 'confusion_matrix',
      'format': 'csv',
      'schema': [
        {'name': 'target', 'type': 'CATEGORY'},
        {'name': 'predicted', 'type': 'CATEGORY'},
        {'name': 'count', 'type': 'NUMBER'},
      ],
      'source': <CONFUSION_MATRIX_CSV_FILE>,
      # Convert vocab to string because for bealean values we want "True|False" to match csv data.
      'labels': list(map(str, vocab)),
    }]
  }

  with open(mlpipeline_ui_metadata_path, 'w') as metadata_file:
    json.dump(metadata, metadata_file)
```

Accordingly, you might try modifying your code like so:

```
import kfp
import kfp.dsl as dsl
from kfp.components import create_component_from_func    

@create_component_from_func
def confusion_visualization(
    matrix_uri: str = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubeflow/pipelines/master/samples/core/visualization/confusion_matrix.csv',
    mlpipeline_ui_metadata_path: kfp.components.OutputPath()
):
    """Provide confusion matrix csv file to visualize as metrics."""
    import json

    metadata = {
        'outputs' : [{
          'type': 'confusion_matrix',
          'format': 'csv',
          'schema': [
            {'name': 'target', 'type': 'CATEGORY'},
            {'name': 'predicted', 'type': 'CATEGORY'},
            {'name': 'count', 'type': 'NUMBER'},
          ],
          'source': matrix_uri,
          'labels': ['rose', 'lily', 'iris'],
        }]
    }
    
    print('Printing the metadata')
    print(metadata)

    with open(mlpipeline_ui_metadata_path, 'w') as metadata_file:
        json.dump(metadata, metadata_file)

@dsl.pipeline(
    name='confusion-matrix-pipeline',
    description='A sample pipeline to generate Confusion Matrix for UI visualization.'
)
def confusion_matrix_pipeline():
    confusion_visualization_task = confusion_visualization('results.json')
    
    
client = kfp.Client()
client.create_run_from_pipeline_func(
    confusion_matrix_pipeline,
    arguments={}
)
```